# servlet mapping in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Sorry about the vague title but I have a servlet with the following mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>SomePackage.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/SomeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

that opens a html file in a different folder and writes to Response. As a result, the images in that html try to load `/servlet/images/someimage.png` instead of `/images/someimage.png`

I know that the image reference in the html is relative and hence it trying to go from the servlet path but I can't change the html page or the servlet code. Is there any why to fix this from the configuration files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the servlet to `/SomeServlet`.

Or create a servlet mapped to `/servlet/images/*.jpg` that forwards to `/images/Xxx.jpg`, where `Xxx` is what matched the wildcard.

What kind of environment are you working in, where you can't change anything?

Comment: The pages post to `/servlet/SomeServlet` and I cannot change the html.

Comment: @JBNitz Migrating from ServletExec with IIS to tomcat. There are only about 10 servlets but  I just have the class files. As for html pages, I have hundreds of pages posting to these servlets and I'm trying to see if there is a way to achieve this without having to change individual pages.

Comment: @JBNitz now, do I have to create a new servlet that extends HttpServlet?

Answer (score 0):

In You HTML file use the context path..

```
<img src ="/CONTEXT/images/someimage.png"/>
```

e.g

```
<img src ="/StackOverOverflow/images/someimage.png"/>
```

*Sorry I didn't notice that you can't change the HTML.*

How about creating a filter which will filter out the images and will forward the call to the servlet if it matches your servlet path? Did you try this?

Comment: If i could change the html files, I know that changing from `src="someimage.png"` to `src="/someimage.png"` will fix it, but I can't modify the html files at this moment.